# Function to merge 'infinite' number of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

// mergeAllArrays takes an open number of arrays and merges them into one large array.

```
function mergeAllArrays() {
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $a = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        array_merge($a, $arg_list[$i]);
    }
    print_r($a);

mergeAllArrays($array1,$array2,$array3)
```

Comes up empty ... of course the individual arrays are defined separately simple non-associative arrays (e.g. `$array1 = array("item1","item2",etc)`)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not simply use array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3)? array_merge() already takes an "infinite"/open number of arguments

Comment: Its a kinda multiple choice if you like. So where user one might want arrays 3,4,and 7 - another user might want all of them, or only one. so the choices are passed to the function to build specific output based on the user choices and yes I am probably coding it badly, but it's just how my mental logic is working right now (i.e. very conceptually and I am trying to piece the bits together). It may be that I end up with using array_merge, but in my initial conceptual tests it was not easy to translate the inputs into a good command.

Comment: $mergeArrayList = array($array3,$array4,$array7); $mergedArrays = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $mergeArrayList);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must assign the new value to $a:

```
// mergeAllArrays takes an open number of arrays and merges them into one large array.
function mergeAllArrays() {
  $numargs = func_num_args();
  $arg_list = func_get_args();
  $a = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
    $a = array_merge($a, $arg_list[$i]);
  }
  print_r($a);
}

mergeAllArrays($array1,$array2,$array3);
```

But I wonder if you really need this, because your function does the same as php native function array_merge (which can also accept multiple arrays).

Comment: doh! Works great thanks! As a new boy, things like that escape me :) reading my original code made absolute sense (in that I had already assigned THE array to $a and thus I was simply adding to it :)

Comment: Spoon-feeding somehow makes SOF less attractive.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use `array_merge`
or if you want using your method only then replace your code with

```
function mergeAllArrays() {
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();

    $a = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $a = array_merge($a, $arg_list[$i]);
    }
    var_dump($a);
}

mergeAllArrays($array1,$array2,$array3);
```

In your code one closing bracket was missing and merge data store varible was missing which I have added